# dual entries of Ubuntu in windows boot loader

Tags: dual-boot

I am using a laptop with pre-installed Windows8.
I installed Ubuntu 14.04 by switching to legacy mode along side with Windows8.
I got the ubuntu entry in windows boot loader menu.Then it was showing some problem so I reinstalled the ubuntu.now the problem is I have got 2 entries for ubuntu....and the thing is that they both run.though I have only one ubuntu.
It is not creating the problem for me,but I want to remove one of them.
please help me asap

Comment: One entry is for grubx64 and the other is for shimx64 which is ubuntu secure boot option. leave it there, it does not harm. but if you want to remove it, uninstall shim or delete shimx64 from efi system partition. but for that you must have disabled secure boot.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'sudo update-grub2'.

Comment: He wrote that he is using Windows Boot Loader, not Grub. No idea why though. :P

Comment: well, he installed windows first and ubuntu afterwards. Obviously he is talking about grub. But cant take it for sure :p

Comment: yeah, maybe. But until he corrects it himself, I assume he's correct when he says Windows Boot Loader. :)

Comment: I would like to make some things clear here,though I have mentioned in my question.I have 2 ubuntu entries in windows boot loader.from there First I select the ubuntu(any 1 of 2)..then I got myself to grub,then Ubuntu GUI....@wedu guide me about shimx64......thank you helpers.